# Can KKT be used in minimization s.t to constant param

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Can KKT be used :

```
min g(x)

s.t x>=constant
where constant > 0
```

I have read this

The Kuhn-Tucker method:
[here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~cajones/math2640/notes4.pdf) says that

This is an alternative, and slightly simpler method for dealing with the common case where there are
positivity constraints, that is constraints of the form
xi ≥ 0 or − xi ≤ 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing $g(x)$ is equivalent to maximizing $-g(x)$. So, you can restate your initial problem as

$$ \max_{x} -g(x) \quad s.t. \; x \ge a \quad ,\text{ where } a \text{ is some constant}$$

and use the standard KKT method.